# Access to web service over ISA, SSL

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, asmx, isaserver

I try to access asmx web service that hosted on IIS behind ISA server and authentication is held by ISA server using certificate (User Certificate => [https] => ISA => Authentication [http] => Web Service). How to invoke service methods using C# client?

Comment: Ask your server administrator. It is not a 'code' action.

Comment: Leppie, I can access to web service over Internet Explorer but I need to access web service from windows application.

Comment: Any time you can access a resource through the browser but not through your program, then it's probably due to the internet proxy server that your browser is using automatically. You need to find out the proxy information and use it programmatically.